# Can't access windows using rEFInd boot manager after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: macos, boot, osx-elcapitan

I use rEFInd to make triple boot option for MBP, after upgrading to El Capitan rEFInd startup menu disappear.

So I reinstall refind, Now startup menu shows my boot option for ubuntu,Mac,Windows7.
ubuntu and Mac working well but windows can't boot.

Answer (score 1):

I found using refindPlus the answer. From memory, when I went through this myself it had to do with the change in file structure some where around El Capitan.

I tried every which way for a few hours and then refindPlus was the answer.

https://github.com/dakanji/RefindPlus

Answer (score 0):

Chameleon boot loader is an old bios boot loader for hackintoshes that would solve your problem. I don't think it has been updated for a long time now, so wouldn't recommend it. But it does answer your question.

**Compile from source version:**

http://forge.voodooprojects.org/p/chameleon/downloads/

**or use pre-compiled installer package (must log in)**

https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/231075-chameleon-24svn-official-pkg-installer/

Answer (score 0):

> I use rEFInd to make triple boot option for MBP, after upgrading to El
> Capitan rEFInd startup menu disappear.

Yes, upgrading your Mac OS will cause the mac os bootloader to override refind. Therefore, you must reactivate refind by reinstalling it after an update or upgrade of mac os.

> So I reinstall refind, Now startup menu shows my boot option for
> ubuntu,Mac,Windows7. ubuntu and Mac working well but windows can't
> boot.

After you install linux on a mac hard drive for a triple boot, linux automatically switches your MacOS Hard drives partition table to a Hybrid MBR (Master Boot Record). This causes windows to attempt to boot your mac using legacy boot, however, most macs are no longer compatible to boot a legacy windows OS. They need to boot in UEFI mode, and so does windows. To do this, you must recreate your mac hard drive into a full GPT partition/disk. Without your mac hard drive having a GPT partition table with a protected master boot record (PMBR), windows won't be able to boot, because it can't boot from a disk with a hybrid partition table.

The steps to fix this, are as follows:

1. Boot your mac into linux, or use a linux live usb to boot into linux.
2. Once booted into linux, open up your terminal.
3. Type `lsblk` to find what the name of your mac hard drive is (i.e. /dev/sda).
4. Once you know the location of your hard drive (most likely /dev/sda), type the following command:
   `sudo gdisk /dev/your-hard-drive` (i.e. `sudo gdisk /dev/sda`).
5. Type `x` for extra functionality.
6. Type `n` to create a new protective MBR table.
7. Type `w` and press enter to save the new partition table to the disk and exit.

Now you should have your partition table back to how MacOS and Windows need it, and you should be able to boot your windows partition just fine. Linux will also boot fine with this new (original) partition table.

Comment: FYI you're answering a question that is 1) off-topic and 2) seven years old.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: Please be sure to flag the original question, too.

Comment: @JeremyCaney - already have - mine is the solitary close-vote.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: Huh, weird, I also flagged it—and it only shows one vote.